# Sexual thoughts coming with full pace to silent mind

Tags: mindfulness, sexuality

I'm being very mindful and aware nowadays.  My mind is now very much quite and I am able to watch handful of thoughts in day to day life.  The problem is at a particular instant of quite mind, sexual thoughts come with full vigour.  Don't know why.

Is there any particular reason of sexual thoughts to come vigorously to nearly quite mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sexual thoughts arise from a combination of the sensuality element ([SN 14.12](https://suttacentral.net/sn14.12/en/sujato)) & the ignorance element ([SN 45.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.001.than.html)). Because the mind still ignorantly believes sex can bring happiness & lasting pleasure, the instinctual & habituated sexual impulse (element) & thoughts still arise. In short, they arise due to wrong view.

Comment: What is the solution then? I mean sex can give someone pleasure, otherwise we wouldn't it if it's painful.

Comment: Medhini Is also correct.  It's both escapism+your reason.  Better if you write about escapism as well.  Will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there any particular reason of sexual thoughts to come vigorously to nearly quite mind?**

Thoughts arise and disappear on their own. If you are plagued by any particular thought, consider that [relishing is the root of suffering](https://suttacentral.net/mn1/en/sujato). Find that delight, look at it and simply understand that "this is not mine, this is not who I am, this is not my self." This simple declaration will loosen your grip on the thoughts and they will disappear. Thoughts and feelings persist because there is relishing. Disavow the relishing and the thoughts and feelings pass like clouds in the sky. Be mindful of your breath as you do this. The breath is very much a part of your life. The thoughts simply come and go.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simply habituation.

The mind is used to input, any input will do. Whether it's thoughts or sound or images, and whether the thoughts are about sex, drugs, rock-n-roll doesn't really matter.

More interesting is that you consider memories popping up a problem. So, there is wanting there. Maybe wanting the peaceful state to continue? Which it won't since everything is impermanent.

There is more to uncover. Keep watching.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you already did the first step and thats

**recognizing its existence**

```
Its just important to separate from self as the answers told you
```

Now why you get them so vigorously when your mind has developed mindful awareness you say ?

Mindfulness comes easy for you in some aspects and hard in others which is normal because everyone has beliefs and habituation about things learned since childhood so filtering that through mindful awareness takes time and ardency.

**So knowing the reason why is the second step**

After that you can more easily divert your attention to something else it doesn't mean avoidance of what you don't like it only means that you can now do what you intend to do with less suffering.

**Diverting your attention to something else is the last step**

Answer (score -1):

The essence of Buddhism is understanding that we can't control our body, our mind and things happening around us. But people tends to involve those things and thus, our emotion attached to those things and start karma cycle.

For example, when we eat a food, at the same time in our mind happening Greed(on our favorite food), Anger (Bad taste, Don't like), etc. And based on those emotional attachment, we taking out the actions which will become karma and reincarnation cycle.

In Accent of Buddhism is eating also a part of life and that is out of our control and so get rid from attached mind such as Greed and Anger, etc., to stop reincarnation cycle.

So, it is natural that you have those kind of mind such as sexual thoughts. And try to understand as it as just a thought and watch as it is until it lose again, as everything as happening in this universe.